# How to save the state of webview page selection/url while navigating in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-webview

I have a dynamic user interface that displays a variable number of tabs based on certain conditions. Each tab contains a web page displayed within an AndroidView wrapper. When navigating between tabs, I aim to preserve the state of the previously viewed webpage, including scroll position and any selections made. This ensures that when returning to the screen, the user sees the same content they left off with.

For Tabs: I am using LazyRow with TabItem as below:

```
data class TabItem(
    val label: String,
    val resourceId: Int? = null,
    val value: String,
)
```

and the tabs are shown like below :

```
@Composable
fun TabsBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    items: List<TabItem>? = emptyList(),
    selected: String? = "",
    onClick: (value: String) -> Unit = {}
) {}
```

Below is my code

```
@Composable
private fun ShowWebPage(
    url: String,
    viewModel: TestViewModel
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val scrollState = remember { ScrollState(0) }
    val webView = remember { WebView(context) }
    var isLoading by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }


    LaunchedEffect(viewModel.needsWebViewRefresh()) {
        if (viewModel.needsWebViewRefresh()) {
            // Reload the web view if the refresh flag is set
            webView.reload()
            // Reset the refresh flag after reloading
            viewModel.resetRefreshFlag()
        }
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        AndroidView(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .verticalScroll(scrollState),
            factory = { context ->
                webView.apply {
                    webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
                        override fun onProgressChanged(view: WebView?, newProgress: Int) {
                            if (progress >= 10) {
                                webView.visibility = View.VISIBLE;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
                            isLoading = true
                        }

                        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                            isLoading = false
                        }


                    }
                    settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                    settings.domStorageEnabled = true
                    this.alpha = 0.99F
                    loadUrl(url)
                }
            },
            update = {
                // This is where you update the WebView content if needed
                it.loadUrl(url)
            }
        )

        // Show progress indicator when loading
        if (isLoading) {
            CircularProgressIndicator(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(30.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.Center)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you display ```Tab``` using ```TabRow``` or not?. And also elaborate your question.

Comment: Its a LazyRow which has buttons as tabs, please see edits.

Comment: You need to use ```HorinzontanPager``` with ```TabRow``` so that Older screen state can be saved

Comment: I cant use it as its used all over app and am stuck using it. Any way to save state in this sceanrio